# how can i call modal component inside a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I use vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/

My parent component like this :

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    ...
        <v-col
        v-for="(item, i) in items"
        :key="i"
        >
        <v-card
        >
            <v-app-bar dark color="grey">
            <v-toolbar-title>Weekly Schedule : {{item.name}}</v-toolbar-title>
            <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
            <modal-datepicker :schedule="item"  />
            </v-app-bar>
        </v-col>
    ...
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import modalDatepicker from "../views/modalDatepicker";
export default {
  components: {modalDatepicker},
};
</script>
```

My child component like this :

```
<template>
    <v-dialog
        :ref="dialog"
        v-model="modal"
        :return-value.sync="date"
    >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="success" dark v-on="on">Show datepicker</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-row justify="center">
            <v-date-picker v-model="date" scrollable>
                <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn text color="primary">OK</v-btn>
            </v-date-picker>
        </v-row> 
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import modalDatepicker from "../views/modalDatepicker";
export default {
  components: {modalDatepicker},
  props: ['schedule'],
  data: () => ({
    date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    modal: false,
  }),
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.schedule)
  },
};
</script>
```

The code above works, but seems inefficient. because every time the loop, it call modal dialog. I want modal to only be called when user click show datepicker button

how do i do that?

Comment: Can you please create a codepen with a minimal reproduction steps..

Comment: @chans I had solve it

Answer (score 0):

Apologies as I am on my mobile. Have you considered having the modal in your parent component outside of the loop?

You could have a data variable to handle your modal e.g

```
modal: {
    open: false,
    schedule: null }
```

Essentially then when your button is clicked you could add a `v-click` with a function that controls this data which in turns handles the content in the modal.

Then on your date picker or modal have a function to handle the update/close to clear this data and handle whatever you need too outside.

Then you could combine this into one component.

I see you have vuex you could also use vuex to control your modal and it’s contents.